Factorized distribution implies independence
I want to show that random variables $R_1$, $\cdots$, $R_n$ are independent iff $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = F_1(x_1) \cdots F_n(x_n)$ where $F$ is distribution function
I use definition of independence using borel sets. i.e., $R_1$, $\cdots$, $R_n$ are independent if for every borel sets $B_i$, $P(R_1 \in B_1, \cdots, R_n \in B_n) = P(R_1 \in B_1) \cdots P(R_n \in B_n)$
One direction is simple: $F(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = P(R_1 \leq x_1, \cdots, R_n \leq x_n) = P(R_1 \leq x_1) \cdots P(R_n \leq x_n) = F_1(x_1) \cdots F_n(x_n)$
My question is, how can I prove other direction? I wonder how can I get argument for arbitary borel sets from $R_i \leq x_i$. It seems obvious as borel set is sigma-field generated by intervals or rays, but I want to prove it rigorously.

What obstructs you when, e.g., $n =2$?

Assume we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}$. First you have to show that for any random variable $X$, $\sigma(X)$ is generated by ${{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \leq x}: x \in \mathbb{R}}$, because it can be shown that this set is a $\pi$-system. Secondly, it can be proven that if $\mathbb{P}(I \cap J) = \mathbb{P}(I)\mathbb{P}(J), \forall I \in \mathcal{I}, J \in \mathcal{J}$, where $\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{J}$ are $\pi$-systems, then this extends to all combinations of sets in $\sigma(\mathcal{I}), \sigma(\mathcal{J})$. Extending to $n >2$ is a bit more work.
